# JavaMail : How to read an email thread

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have an email thread that i need to parse. I am using the JavaMail API to read the content of the email. Here is my code so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException, IOException {

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/atomar/Desktop/Projects/CRM/mysamples/test.txt"));

            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String content = collect(bin);
            Session s = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s, is);

            DataSource ds = new FileDataSource(new File("C:/Users/atomar/Desktop/Projects/CRM/mysamples/test.txt"));

            MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(ds);
            System.out.println(mp.getCount());

            MimeBodyPart bp1 = (MimeBodyPart) mp.getBodyPart(0);

            System.out.println(bp1.getContent().toString());

            for(Enumeration<Header> e = bp1.getAllHeaders(); e.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                Header hd = e.nextElement();

                System.out.println(hd.getName());
                System.out.println(hd.getValue());
            }


}

public static String collect(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
    String line;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
    }
```

And here is the email message:

```
From: Dxx, Sxxx (CWM-NR) 
Sent: Monday,March 02, 2015 6:18 AM
To: ons; +CMV; Sart, Rhi; +cWK-

Application-Monitoring-team; +R00; +Dps Group; +C-TCS-

OPS
Subject: RE: FATAL: /home/coprod/shells/cron/loades FAILED FOR 

BUSINESS DATE 2015xxxx


Team,

Informed Igor, and he will look into the issue. 


Thanks & Regards, 
Das
-----Original Message-----
From: Ns [mailto:opscron@xxxxx.com] 
Sent: 2015, March, 02 6:00 AM
To: +CPS-DEV; Sat, Ru; +-HAWcm-iGAK; 

+R00; +Dops Group; +CCS-OPS
Subject: FATAL: /home/coprod/shells/cron/lot_trades FAILED FOR BUSINESS 

DATE 2015xxxx

Bus Date  :  2015xxxx
Log File  :  /ho/backofce/ls/lod_narades.20152 
Error     :  Input file </e/boe/adles/NAS27.txt> does not 

exist. 

Log excerpt:   


==================================================================================

===================================
   START        :  Mon Mar  2 06:00:08 EST 2015              SCRIPT NAME IS : 

/he/crod/se/cron/lorades
   USER NAME IS : gntyu              HOST NAME IS : ny8678i01 
   DB_SERVER IS : PROD_SERVER           ARG LIST:   

 => 06:00:08 : Using input file: /me/boshe/aes/NA27.txt   


---------------------------------
```

First of all, is this the correct way to read this message ? So, now, my

```
System.out.println(mp.getCount());
```

gives me a count of 1. I think it should be 2 as there are two messages here. Interestingly, if i try to get the headers and content, i get all the stuff for the second message !.

Also, if i read the file using

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(s, is);
```

and then try to iterate over the headers and content, i get all the stuff in the first message ! Any ideas how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've wasted a lot of effort reading the file in, converting it to a String, then converting it back to bytes so the MimeMessage constructor can use it.  Just give the file to the MimeMessage constructor directly.  Maybe use [javax.mail.util.SharedFileInputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/SharedFileInputStream.html).

I don't know why you're constructing a MimeMultipart from the same file data; that's completely unnecessary and wrong.

Note that the sample message you have has no Content-Type header, so JavaMail is going to assume it's just a single part message with a text/plain MIME type, which seems to be what it is.  The stuff below the "Original Message" separator looks to a human like an attachment or a forwarded message, but it's not reflected in the MIME structure of the message.  As far as MIME (and JavaMail) is concerned, it's just part of the text of the single body of the message.

You might find the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples) helpful, especially its "-m" option that allows it to read a MIME message from a file, parse it, and display its structure or content.

Comment: correct, now i get it. the MimeMultiPart message is only if the email has any attachments (parts). the stuff below the "Original Message" separator is the first email and the email on the top is the second email. I want to get the content of these two emails in separate objects. Is that possible using JavaMail API ?

Comment: No, not directly.  The MimeMessage constructor expects the input to contain a single message.  And in this case, per the (lack of) MIME headers on the message, it does.  This is just a message where someone has done the equivalent of copy and pasting the original message at the bottom of their reply.  You can try to parse the content of a message and guess whether someone has done this, but you're stuck with a bunch of heuristics that won't always work.  It's not really "two MIME messages", it's more like "one message with some content that sort of looks like another message".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments everyone. I guess there is no easy way to isolate individual emails from an email thread. I will have to come up with some pattern matching techniques to figure out where one email ends and another begins.

Thanks